# Como calcular la media de elementos que se encuentran en posiciones pares de un vector

Tags: c++, array, c, vectores

-Hola amigos, estoy tratando de obtener la media de elementos par e impar de un vector, cuando trato  de obtener la media de elementos en la posición par del vector me dice que la cantidad es  0, les dejo  el código para que me entiendan mejor

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

/*

3. Escriba una función que reciba un arreglo de N números flotantes,
 y luego calcule la media de los elementos que se encuentran en las posiciones pares y la media de los elementos que se encuentran
  en las posiciones impares.

*/

void vector();

void par();

float v[100];

int i,e;

double media=0;

int main(){
    
    
vector();   

printf("\n");
par();
    
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void vector(){
    
    
    printf("Digite la cantidad de elementos del vector : ");
    scanf("%i",&e);
    
    printf("\n");
    
    for(i=0;i<e;i++){
        printf("Digite el elemento [%i] del vector  : ",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&v[i]);
        
        
    }
    
    
}

void par(){
    
    for(i=0;i<e;i++){
        if(i %2 == 0){
    
        media = media + v[i];
        
        }
    }

printf("La media de elementos en posiciones pares : %i  ",media);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Tienes un error en

```
printf("La media de elementos en posiciones pares : %i  ",media);
```

Tu variable `media` es `double` por lo que debes usar `%f` y estas utilizando `%i` que es para `int`

El problema ocurre porque los `double` usan 8 bytes y los `int` 4 bytes

Si utilizas `%f` funcionará correctamente

```
printf("La media de elementos en posiciones pares : %f  ",media);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, increíble  como un fallo mínimo me dio tantos problemas xd

Comment: @JulioRomero, Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.